Причастие с НЕ здесь должно писаться раздельно?
Нельзя отдыхать на не оборудованных для купания пляжах.
Являются ли слова "для купания" в данном случае зависимыми для причастия "оборудованных", позволяя писать НЕ раздельно?

не оборудованных для купания - есть зависимое слово с предлогом. "Частица НЕ пишется раздельно:
с причастиями, имеющими при себе зависимые слова"

Для купания не оборудованы, а отдыхать-то почему нельзя? :))

В том контексте отдых включает купание.

Желательно редактирование предложения, например:
Нельзя купаться в необорудованных и запрещенных для купания водоемах.
Тему можно посмотреть https://vk.com/wall-212823514_675
Сочетаний вида   "на не оборудованных для купания пляжах" лучше  избегать. С одной стороны, требуется раздельное написание НЕ при наличии зависимого слова, а другой — такая определительная конструкция имеет утвердительный характер.
